# How to use useContext changed value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, web-development-server

I am using useContext to pass the account name to all the pages that I have created in app.js.

> **contextProvider.jsx**

import { createContext, useState } from 'react';

```
export const LoginContext = createContext(null);

const ContextProvider = ({children}) => {

    const [ account, setAccount ] = useState('');
    
    return (
        <LoginContext.Provider value={{ account, setAccount }}>
            {children}
        </LoginContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default ContextProvider;
```

Now I am using it in app.js for making it available for all pages.

> **app.js**

```
import ContextProvider from './context/ContextProvider';
export default function app(){
return (
    <ContextProvider>
       <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
              {/* home page where i changing the account value. My header component is wrapped inside this MainPage-component */}
              <Route exact path='/home-services' element={<HouseDeckHomeServicesMainPage city={city} setCity={setCity} handleData={handleData} />} />

              <Route exact path='/home-services/about-us' element={<HouseDeckHomeServicesAnotherPage />} />
      
           </Routes>
       </BrowserRouter>
    </ContextProvider>
  );
```

}

Then I recalling the variables in **LoginContext** from **contextProvider.jsx** to change or set them to a partcular value.

> **Header.jsx**

```
export default function Header(){
const {account, setAccount} = React.useContext(LoginContext)
// let I am doing in header.jsx
setAccount("hello")
return (
   <div>{account}</div>
)
```

}

Suppose i am doing **setAccount("Hello")** in my **Header.jsx** to change it.
The **LoginContext** variable **account** changed. I checked by printing it.

Now I want to use the same value that I stored in **account** in other pages.

I don't know how to use that value.

Right now I am doing

> **AnotherPage.jsx**

```
export default function AnotherPage() {
    const {account} = React.useContext(LoginContext)
    // I want to print the value of account that i changed from 
    // null to "hello" in this page but i am getting undefined 
    // here.
    console.log(account)
    return (
        <div>{account}</div>
    )
}
```

But it is taking the default value of **account** that is **null** which is not what I want.
I want to use the changed value.
Please help.

Comment: If `Content` component is receiving a null context value then it seems it is being rendered ***outside*** the `ContextProvider` component. Please update your question to include properly formatted and readable code snippets instead of images.

Comment: **Context** is receiving its value as I said in the question. I think you haven't read the question properly, please read it line by line you will understand what I am saying. I am saying it again "I want to use the value of assigned context variable **account** in other components too as I posted in app.js but I don't know how to declare and use them as I showed in AnotherPage.jsx . "

Comment: I don't think you've quite grasped the concept of Context API. Kindly refer to the [official Context API docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). I'm sure you'll solve your problem.

Comment: Also, why are you setting your initial `account` state to be the `LoginContext` Context itself? Please do try to update your question to include [full and complete, reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I used it as ** "" ** initially but it was not working, So, I searched for it and get that answer but it was not correct.

Comment: here the updated code and its not working too.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue you describe here in this minimal, running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-use-usecontext-changed-value-w0o7sf) demo.

Comment: You are doing it correct. Please consider adding routes between components. It will help me a lot. My header component in wrapped in every routing component because it is dynamic.

Comment: That should make no difference, but for the sake of discussion, sure, I placed one of the components on a route. It still doesn't reproduce the issue as you describe. Perhaps you could provide a *running* codesandbox that *does* reproduce the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: Wrap header into another component and use that function name instead of using header in app and then try it. I've done it and faced the error.

Comment: I'm telling you, it doesn't matter how deeply you nest `Header` or any other component, if they are both in the ReactSubTree of the the same `ContextProvider` component they will have access to the same context value. I've updated my CSB and it still works as I'd expect, without issue.

Comment: I just tried in your sandbox bro. And I faced the error.

Comment: What are you doing differently then? ‍♂️  Please share a complete example for what you are doing that is producing any issues? Feel free to fork my sandbox, create the issue, save it, and share the link.

Comment: Give me sometime

Comment: I tried and it's like sometimes works and sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

You propably dont have your `Header.jsx` outside of you `ContextProvider`.
Try to wrap whole App component in it instead of just routes

Comment: Like I import ContextProvider.jsx in every component and wrap it.

Comment: no, you need to wrap it all in one provider. Because every new use of contextProvider.Provider will create new context with separate state. For components that share one state you need to wrap them in one context

Comment: that's what i did in app.js

Comment: You have your header and routes in same wrapper? without any aditional nested wrapper? just one unique?

Comment: My header is a dynamic component which changes in every page. I used it in every page.

Comment: ok, my bad sorry. I though so because according to documentation, defaultValue in createContext is used only when component is not wrapped in working provider

Comment: No worries thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced exactly your problem.

Time to use `useMemo`:

```js
const dataMemo = useMemo(() => {
    return {
        account, setAccount
    }
}, [account, setAccount])

return <LoginContext.Provider value={dataMemo}>
    {children}
</LoginContext.Provider>
```

Don't forget `import {useMemo} from 'react'` on the top

Hope it can help ^^

Comment: how do i access account everytime when i need it to display